# Flutter - navigate back to specific tab on a page with Navigator.pop(context)

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In my app, I have a homepage that has 5 tabs on the bottom. On each tabbed page, there is an app bar that has a '+' symbol as an action, which navigates you to a different page. The navigation with that '+' button to the new page is done with the following code, alongside the Flutter Platform Widgets package:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
    .push(
  platformPageRoute(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Page1(),
  ),
);
```

I use the platformPageRoute feature as an easy way to navigate with a native feel. Now, that works fine to navigate to a new page, but the issue comes when I use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

to navigate back to the original page. When I use that to navigate back to that original page, it pays no attention to the tab that was selected originally. For example, if I were originally on the second tab on the homepage and then use the '+' button on that tab and then finally use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

on that new page, it returns the first tab of the homepage. Is there any way of ensuring when I use the above command, it goes to the right tab? I have tried something along the lines of:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, '/homepageTab2');
```

alongside a named route, to return to the correct tab on the homepage, although that returns a black screen. Why might that be? I have also tried using:

```
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                platformPageRoute(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) =>
                      HomePage(selectedPage: 1),
                ),
                (route) => false,
              );
```

This does not work either, since it returns the selected/correct page tab content, but with the first tab selected. In addition, the other
'problem' for me is that the animation is a 'push' one and that doesn't 'match' with the animation when I have more often used

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

to navigate back to a screen. Is there a way to maybe use `pushAndRemoveUntil` but then change the animation to match a `pop` animation?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have just noticed that with the situation I have described above, it is actually returning the correct screen content when I use `Navigator.pop(context);` but the tab in the tab bar at the bottom is showing as the first tab, in the second tab's position, essentially duplicating the first tab, until I navigate to a new tab and back, at which time it shows the correct tab in the correct position. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue wasn't related to `Navigator.pop(context);` being used. It was the way I was controlling the selected tab. I'm posting this as an answer incase it helps someone else.

Initially, I created `late` values for a tab controller and the current selected page, like so:

```
late TabController _tabController;
late ScrollController _scrollController;
late int _selectedPage;
```

Then, I created a list of widgets that represented the actual page to display for each selected tab:

```
List<Widget> _pageWidgets = <Widget>[
  Page1();
  Page2();
  Page3();
  Page4();
  Page5();
];
```

Then (and I think this was the bit that wasn't working) I used `initState()` as follows:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialising a value that allows the 'final' page selector to be changed
    _selectedPage = widget.selectedPage;

    // Initialising the tab controller
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 5,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: _selectedPage,
    );

    // updating the tab index when a new item is selected
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _selectedPage = _tabController.index;
        //_tabIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    });

    // Creating the scroll controller
    _scrollViewController = ScrollController();

    // Scrolling view to top when a new tab is selected
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _scrollViewController
            .jumpTo(_scrollViewController.position.minScrollExtent);
      });
    });
  }
```

I then controlled the page content like this:

```
body: _pageWidgets.elementAt(_selectedPage),
```

I'm not 100% sure why this wasn't working, although I believe it would have something to do with the fact that `initState()` would only be called during the build and therefore placing the functionality inside there would mean changes wouldn't be detected. Either way, my new method, which works perfectly, is:

```
  /// Controls the screen to display first
  int _index = 0;

  /// Creating a navigation key to control tab bar navigation
  final _navigationKey = GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState>();
```

Then, within the `Scaffold()` I show the page content like this:

```
body: _pageWidgets.elementAt(_index),
```

And finally, within the navigation bar (which is the `CurvedNavigationBar()` package from pub.dev) I give it a key and the index:

```
key: _navigationKey,
index: _index,
```

And this controls it perfectly, showing the correct tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-pages of a `TabBarView` cannot be navigated using `Navigator`.

You can use `TabController` to go to your desired tab page after awaiting `Navigator.push()`:

```dart
await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
    .push(
  platformPageRoute(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Page1(),
  ),
);

tabController.animateTo(<index of tab>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually did manage to get `Navigator.pop(context);` displaying the right tab when going back to the homepage. The issue was essentially that my method for controlling the tab selected wasn't working. I've refreshed that, now with a `GlobalKey()` and it is working perfectly. I'll pop it in an answer incase it helps anyone.